# How do I create a new mysql database/schema through bash?

Tags: mysql, bash

I am writing a bash script to create a new empty mysql database, based on an already existing database. My plan is to go through the following steps:

1. Create a blank database with user defined name
2. Populate that database using mysql dump, by bringing in data structure from an already existing data

I can am able to create the new data through root user but need the non-root user to be able to work with that database. My problem is at the step where I am trying to grnat privileges to the non-root user.

The error I am getting is:

> ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

Here is what my bash snippet looks like:

```
# drop database, if previous one exists
mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER_ROOT} -p${DB_PASSWORD_ROOT} -e "drop database if exists ${target_db}"
echo "dropped the DB"

# create a new database
mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER_ROOT} -p${DB_PASSWORD_ROOT} -e "create database if not exists ${target_db}"
echo "created new DB"

sudo mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER_ROOT} -p${DB_PASSWORD_ROOT} -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${DB_USER}'@'${DB_HOST}' with grant option;"
echo "granted permissions"


mysql -h ${DB_HOST} -u ${DB_USER_ROOT} -p${DB_PASSWORD_ROOT} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
echo "flushed permissions"
```

I wish to complete be able to work with the newly created database using the non-root ${DB_USER}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never mind. I found the solution. That . in 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO' is the troublemaker. I changed that to the .* and it worked fine.